Api Controller Method Not Called but http 200 ok is returned
I added a controller to an existing application in which I call a method
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/bank-data")]
public class BankDataController : ControllerBase
{
    #region FIELDS

    private readonly IService _service;

    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTORS

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service"></param>
    public BankDataController(IService service)
    {
        _service = service ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(service));
    }

    #endregion

    #region METHODS
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Bank Detail
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{code}/data/{progressive}")]
    [OpenApiOperation("getBankData")]
    [ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(BankDataDetailDto), statusCode: StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(ForbiddenResponse), statusCode: StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
    [ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(BadRequestResponse), statusCode: StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(UnAuthorizedResponse), statusCode: StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
    [ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(InternalServerErrorResponse), statusCode: StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetBankData(Guid code, int progressive)
    {
        var result = await _service.GetBankDataDetail(code, progressive);
        return Ok(result);
    }



    #endregion
}

I try this method with swagger, but breakpoint that I put to test the method is never triggered
This is the url print by swagger -> http://localhost:44747/api/v1/bank-data/826acae7-6a79-4337-88dd-04377a6db090/data/11
But the response are:
date: Tue,02 Jul 2024 15:03:42 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 transfer-encoding: chunked 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET

I don't have any exceptions, because the http code 200 ok is returned to me, but I can't understand what's wrong

Are you attaching to the right process?

Yes, I put the breakpoint in the method but it never fires, and immediately returns 200 ok with no response of any kind
